# Script shell : Take variable number of arguments after few arguments passed before

Tags: python, bash, shell

Hye, I am currrently trying to make a cli command, that will pass arguments to the python script.

For example my python script will be executed based on the given parameter,

```
./run.py <START-DATE> <END-DATE> -site <SITE-ID>(ranging from 1 to n)
```

The question here is, how can I pass the variables from the bash script to my python script?

What I have researched is I can take the arguments using the variables $1 , $2, $3, etc, and $@ if we don't know how many the aguments will be passed.

The problem here is,

My `<START-DATE>` `<END-DATE>` and `-site` are fixed to 1 variable only, which is $1,$2 and $3 respectively, so how can I use $@ but only after $3?

My code test.sh for now :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [ $1 -ne "" ] && [ $2 -ne "" ] && [ $3 -ne "" ] && [ $4 -ne "" ]; //minimum 1 argument for site// then
    /usr/bin/python2.6 run.py $1 $2 $3
else
    echo "Please insert the correct number of arguments"
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by `so how can I use $@ but only after $3`?

Comment: `shift; shift; shift; "$@"`

Comment: @Malik I mean take variable number of arguments after the first three fixed arguments

Comment: @jordanm Will try it . Thanks

Comment: You need to use spaces more carefully — the `[$1 -ne ""]` notation needs a space after the `[` and another before the `]`.  The first is the name of the command; when invoked by the name `[`, the command looks at the last argument and requires that to be `]`.  (Being ultra-pedantic, the empty string before the `]` means that the last argument is just `]`, but the contents within is mal-formed because there is no right-hand argument for the `-ne` operator.  You need the space, in other words.)

Comment: @jordanm: you can abbreviate that to `shift 3; "$@"`.  @yunaranyancat: Do you need `-site site1 -site site2 -site site3` or do you need `-site site1 site2 site3`?  If the latter, why is the `-site` used at all?  And why doesn't your test code show the `-site` option? Note that before you shift, you need to save: `start="$1"; end="$2"; shift 2; python run.py "$start" "$end" -site "$@"` for the non-repeating variant. Also, the error message should probably be more like `echo "Usage: $0 start end site [...]" >&2` explaining how to use the command, rather than simply saying "you got it wrong".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's the latter. I just need to pass all the arguments to the python script, it will handle all of the arguments passed, handling errors in passing number of args , etc. To make it simple, this script only test number of arguments passed before passing it to a python script that handles everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$#` to find the number of arguments passed to the bash script. And if all is well, use `$@` to pass all the arguments to the Python script. Something like:

```
# At least 4 arguments should be passed
if [ $# -gt 3 ]
then
    /usr/bin/python2.6 run.py $@
else
    echo "Please insert the correct number of arguments"
fi
```